# In mysql, what is an efficient way to get only rows in a table by a distinct value in one of that table's columns?

Tags: sql, mysql, select, performance, distinct

I'm relatively new to mysql so bear with me.

I have a table that looks a bit like this:

```
ID | Name | Location  

0  | John | Los Angeles  
1  | Joe  | San Jose  
2  | Jane | New York  
3  | Sal  | Boise  
4  | Jay  | New York  
5  | Kate | San Jose
```

I need a `SELECT` statement that gets all rows, with the exception that if Location is repeated, that row is ignored. The result should look something like this:

```
0  | John | Los Angeles  
1  | Joe  | San Jose  
2  | Jane | New York  
3  | Sal  | Boise
```

The important thing is that my table is very, very large, with hundreds of thousands of rows. Most things I've tried as ended up with select statements that take **literally 30+ minutes to complete!**

Comment: Well, the problem is that what you're asking for is undefined.  What should the other fields be?  Should they be the first occurrence  (lowest ID)?  Should they be the newest occurrence  (highest ID)?  Should it be ordered by name?  Something else?  You need to define that first, since the exact query will depend on what you're trying to get out...

Comment: I want the entire row, and I don't particularly care which row with the distinct Location is the one I get. In the example result, I could get "4 | Jay | New York" instead of "2 | Jane | New York" and it doesn't matter to me - only that I get one of the two. This might sound odd but it's what I need. In addition, thank you Nishant for fixing the formatting in my question.

Comment: Databases in general don't like ambiguity very much.  Your query should be 100% deterministic and unambiguous.  Otherwise you're doing it in the wrong place.  Figure out the rules by which the data should adhere, and then use those rules to build your query...

Comment: How about order by non-nullable field like ID `select * from myloc group by place order by id;` (I am really scared by -1s in the responses)

Comment: By using an order by and group by as well as implementing an index for the location field, I was able to cut down on my selection time by a ridiculous amount, queries now taking <30 seconds, as well as make sure to grab the item with lowest id from the group (not necessary for my uses, but I won't argue with ircmaxell). Thank you very much. That article was very helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
SELECT mt1.ID, mt1.Name, mt1.Location 
FROM mytable mt1
JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) AS ID 
        FROM Mytable 
        GROUP BY location) mt2
    ON mt1.id = mt2.Id
```

The derived table get the minimum id for each location. Then joins to the table to pull the rest of the data.

Incidentally ID is a horrible choice for naming the id field. Please think about using tablenameID instead. It is helpful for reporting not to have the same name for the id fields in differnt tables and it makes if FAR less likely that you will make an accidental join mistake and join tothe ID in the wrong table. It also makes the PK/FK relationships easier to see in my opinion.

Comment: The names of the fields are hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, Name, Location
FROM table
GROUP BY Location
```

Comment: I assume you are still editing your answer, because this is not going to work !?

Comment: @cdonner Why isn't this going to work? The OP did not specify which duplicate row to skip. this will return a random row for every group.

Comment: Please explain the downvote. I do agree that the results will be non deterministic, but the OP doesn't seem to care

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on Location? That should help improve the speed a lot.

Comment: Note: if you do an [`EXPLAIN <query>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) and insert your `SELECT ...` statement in the query slot, you'll get some good information about what indeces are being used, etc.

Comment: That's a good point. It would tell him what exactly is wrong as hundrends of thousands of rows isn't that much to cause performance problems.

Answer (score -2):

you can use

`SELECT * FROM tbl GROUP BY Location`

creating an index on Location can dramatically help reduce the querying time.

Also if there are more number of columns in your table, specifying only the required columns instead of using * will improve performance further.

Comment: I'm not the -1, but.. if you're not grouping by name, it's value is undefined. I know MySQL lets us do this, but it's still not a great idea. It should be just `SELECT Distinct(Location) FROM tbl` or `SELECT Location FROM tbl GROUP BY Location`

Comment: Not the -1 either, but having more columns returned than listed in the `GROUP BY` clause is ambiguous and will return ambiguous results.  Give [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html) a read since it goes into these issues and more...

Comment: @Nish - yeah, what @ircmax said :)

Comment: yes it does work but even i landed up on the same link that ircmaxell has mentioned and now i feel its wrong! That link explains it nicely.